# Issue with CLlocationManager in iOS 8

Tags: objective-c, cllocationmanager

When I configure the CLlocationManager with this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
self.locationManager.delegate = self;
self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyHundredMeters;
if([self.locationManager respondsToSelector:@selector(requestAlwaysAuthorization)]) {
    [self.locationManager requestAlwaysAuthorization];
    // Or [self.locationManager requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
}    [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
```

}

and the set the location delegate

```
#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailWithError: %@", error);
    UIAlertView *errorAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Failed to Get Your Location" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [errorAlert show];
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
    NSLog(@"didUpdateToLocation: %@", newLocation);
    CLLocation *currentLocation = newLocation;

    if (currentLocation != nil) {
        self.textLongitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.longitude];
        self.textLatitude.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.8f", currentLocation.coordinate.latitude];
    }
}
```

Don´t send the alert for authorized, but the Info.plist is complete

[image]

when go to settings and change in settings -> privacy -> localize and change the status for "always", and restart the app this status is clean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` is misspelled in the plist.